# buffering with time and custom event

Tags: javascript, buffer, rxjs

I started using `rxjs` yesterday. i would like to achieve the following behavior:

I want my buffer to be produced with both time and custom events.
Imagine, every 2000 ms my buffer is produced (like standard `bufferWithTime` function behavior) and for some special event, a buffer is produced and the timer, is re initialized.

Here is a basic representation :

[image]

Content of buffer `A`: `[1, 2]`, `B`: `[3, 4, 5]`, `C`: `[6, 7]`, `D`: `[8, 9]`.

Time segments `A`, `B`, `D` have the same duration, 2000 ms.

Time segment `C` was shorter because special event `7` was triggered and buffer was produced.

How can i do this ?

Comment: Can you specify a marble diagram of the intended behaviour? Examples of marble diagrams here ; http://rxmarbles.com/. That basically presenting the inputs and the expected outputs on a timeline.

Comment: @user3743222 i hope it is more understandable with this diagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7d95cz3/))?

```
// Helper functions
function randomDelay(bottom, top) {
  return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( 1 + top - bottom ) ) + bottom;
}

// Simulation of random sequence
var source$ = Rx.Observable
  .range(1, 30)
  .concatMap(function (x) {
    return Rx.Observable.of(x).delay(randomDelay(10,500));
  });

var intervalBetween = 1000; // should be 2000ms in your case
var dummyStart$ = Rx.Observable.return({});
var specialEvent$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click');
var opening$ = dummyStart$.concat(specialEvent$).flatMapLatest(function(x){return Rx.Observable.timer(0, intervalBetween)});
var buffers$ = source$.buffer(opening$).skip(1);

source$.subscribe(function(x){console.log('source', x)})

buffers$.subscribe(function(buffer){
   console.log('buffer', buffer);
});
```

The idea here is to use the `buffer` operator with the signature [`Rx.Observable.prototype.window(windowBoundaries);`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/window.md). That should give you non-overlapping buffers which emit synchronized with the `windowBoundaries` signal.

There is a small trick (`dummyStart`) to kickoff the timer immediately with a false `specialEvent`. That produce an empty buffer as first value, which is removed by `skip(1)`.

Comment: thanks ! i changed a bit your code to match what i need : http://jsfiddle.net/y7d95cz3/1/ can you give me your opinion ? i wanted to subscribe to special code too. i don't understand the point of `dummyStart`

Comment: you do need the `dummyStart` though, otherwise till you click once (special event) no buffer will be emitted. In the fiddle you sent, if you move the mouse, and never click, you will see that no buffer is emitted.